Flutter Speech to text
I am currently facing an issue with the speech_to_text package on newer Android versions (33+). Recent Android updates have imposed limitations, removing support for many languages. I need to capture speech in Arabic from various dialects and display the recognized text in Arabic on the UI, but I'm unable to do so because of these changes. What are my options for resolving this?

For more details follow this doc:

Android SDK 30 or later If you are targeting Android SDK,
i.e. you set your targetSDKVersion to 30 or later,
then you will need to add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml right after the permissions section.
See the example app for the complete usage.

<queries> 
    <intent> 
        <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" /> 
    </intent>
</queries>


In my project I have these permissions still the issue remains.
